# (Terraform) Error 403: Cloud Run Admin API has not been used in project 905986752003 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.d

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

On **GCP**, I applied this **Terraform** code below to run **the Cloud Run service "renderer"**:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "renderer" {
  name     = "renderer"
  location = "asia-northeast1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/${var.project_id}/renderer:latest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I got this error:

> Error creating Service: googleapi: Error 403: Cloud Run Admin API has
> not been used in project 905986752003 before or it is disabled. Enable
> it by visiting
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/run.googleapis.com/overview?project=905986752003
> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
> the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

So, I went to the url https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/run.googleapis.com/overview?project=905986752003 shown in this error above:

[image]

Then, enabled **Cloud Run API**:

[image]

Then, applied this **Terraform** code again:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "renderer" {
  name     = "renderer"
  location = "asia-northeast1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/${var.project_id}/renderer:latest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, I could run **the Cloud Run service "renderer"**:

[image]

Now, I want to enable **Cloud Run API** with **Terraform** code:

[image]

Is it possible to enable **Cloud Run API** with **Terraform** code and if it's possible, how do I enable **Cloud Run API** with **Terraform** code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to enable **Cloud Run API** with **Terraform** code. So, you need to add this **Terraform** code:

```
resource "google_project_service" "cloud_run_api" {
  service = "run.googleapis.com"
}
```

Then, you also need to add **"depends_on"** block with **"google_project_service.cloud_run_api"** to wait for **Cloud Run API** to be enabled:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "renderer" {
  name     = "renderer"
  location = "asia-northeast1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/${var.project_id}/renderer:latest"
      }
    }
  }
  depends_on = [ // Here
    google_project_service.cloud_run_api
  ]
}
```

Otherwise, you will get the same error:

> Error creating Service: googleapi: Error 403: Cloud Run Admin API has
> not been used in project 905986752003 before or it is disabled. Enable
> it by visiting
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/run.googleapis.com/overview?project=905986752003
> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
> the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

This is the full **Terrafrom** code:

```
resource "google_project_service" "cloud_run_api" {
  service = "run.googleapis.com"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "renderer" {
  name     = "renderer"
  location = "asia-northeast1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/${var.project_id}/renderer:latest"
      }
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    google_project_service.cloud_run_api
  ]
}
```

In addition, you can find **the Service name "run.googleapis.com"** in the page redirected to after you enable **Cloud Run API**:

```
resource "google_project_service" "cloud_run_api" {
  service = "run.googleapis.com" // Service name
}
```

So, after you enable **Cloud Run API**:

[image]

You are redirected to this page:

[image]

Then, you can find **the Service name "run.googleapis.com"** in **Details** section:

[image]